# DateRangePicker in a React-Admin application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I want to use material ui's [DateRangePicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/) in my React-Admin app.

But when i do an `npm install @material-ui/pickers`, I get:

```
While resolving: test-admin@0.1.0
Found: react@18.2.0
node_modules/react
  react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
node_modules/@material-ui/core
  peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/pickers@3.3.10
  node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
    @material-ui/pickers@"*" from the root project
```

Does this indicate I need to downgrade to React 16 or 17?

Is there any way around this where I can use `DateRangePicker` with an app that uses React 18?

My `package.json` dependencies include:

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
    ...
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-admin": "^4.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  },
  ...
```

Comment: If you don't mind, please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can check here in [MUI docs](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/#installation). Your installation package name is different from the one you're using. It should be `@mui/x-date-pickers`. Make sure you have installed/updated peer dependencies before installing `pickers`. Try these commands:

1️⃣ Install peer dependencies first:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

2️⃣ Now install pickers:

```
npm install @mui/x-date-pickers
```

Note: You requires to install a Date library as well to use `Mui DatePickers`. e.g. `dayjs`, `date-fns`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed this. I also see the DateRangePicker requires a MUI "pro" plan.